# Application works less than 24 hours and alway throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, shopify, digital-ocean

This is the app for rendering latest 250 orders every 20 minutes from Shopify to google sheets.
(ubuntu, node js, digital ocean)

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json');
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');
const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
);
const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'shopname.myshopify.com',
  apiKey: 'key',
  password: 'pas'
});
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: client});
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: client});

let links = [];

async function runDrive(ord, sku){
    const resDrive = await drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 1,
    q: sku,
    spaces: 'drive',
    });
    const files = resDrive.data.files;
    let link;
    if (files.length) {
      link = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${files[0].id}/view`;
    } else {
      link = 'No files found.';
    }
    console.log([ord, sku, link])
    links.push([ord, sku, link])
}

async function gsrun(){
  links = [];
  
  // Shopify - Get orders list
  let orders = await shopify.order.list({ limit: 250 });

  for (const ord of orders){
    for(const item of ord.line_items){
      await runDrive(ord.order_number, item.sku)
    }
  }

  // Sheets - Update cells
  const clearRange = {
    spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
    range: 'Data!A3:G700'
  }
  const updateData = {
      spreadsheetId: 'spreadsheetId',
      range: 'Data!A3',
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      resource: { values: links},
  };
  await sheets.spreadsheets.values.clear(clearRange);
  console.log('Sheet cleaned')
  await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(updateData);
  console.log('Sheet updated')

  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('repeat');
    gsrun();
  }, 1200000);
}

gsrun();
```

It works less than twenty-four hours and alway throws this error:
[image: node js error]
It's my first application.
How to fix it? Should I run the script somewhere outside?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I says in the error that you have not handled an error in a `Promise.` It also states that this will terminate Node.js. You must identify what Promise is not being handled properly and address the issue there. I'm not sure about Google Sheets and what it's doing and I don't see any Promises in the code you've provided.

Comment: @daddygames every `await` call implicitly expects a Promise.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you :) So that still means one of those `await` calls is failing to fulfill it's `Promise.` I think I am correct on that part.

Comment: Yes definitely. It's hard to see the details of the error from the OP but clearly there should be a `try / catch` around something.

Comment: Thanks! After wrapping in try / catch it works a few days without interrupting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wrapping in try / catch it works without interrupting.